# Finding the Number of strings in a File

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to write a very small program that will check the number of sub strings in a large text file. All it will do is count the first 2000 lines of the text file, find any "TTT" sub-strings, count them, and set a variable to that total. I'm a bit new to shell, so any help would be amazingly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

$counter=(head -2000 [file name] | grep TTT | grep -o TTT | wc -l)
echo $counter
```

Comment: Doesn't it work? You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: It gives a syntax error, Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: You have to use `counter=` instead of `$counter=`. The first `grep TTT` can be skipped, by the way.

Comment: probably you meant `counter=$(<pipe command>)`

Comment: What does your input file look like? is there "TTT" multiple times on one line?

Comment: Check http://shellcheck.net/ before asking here about syntax errors.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth you might `awk` better suited for this task:

```
awk -F"ttt" '{j=(NF-1)+j}END{print j}' filename
```

This will split each record in your file by delimiter "ttt". Then it counts the number of fields, subtracts one, and adds that to the total.

A file like:

```
ttt tttttt something
1 5 ttt
tt
one more ttt record
```

Would be split (visualizing with pipe delim) like:

```
| || something
1 5 |
tt
one more | record
```

Counting the number of fields per record:

```
4
2
1
2
```

Subtracting one from that:

```
3 
1
0
1
```

Which totals to 5, which is how many "ttt" substrings are present.

To incorporate this into your script (and fixing your other issue):

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=$(awk -F"ttt" '{j=(NF-1)+j}END{print j}' filename)
echo $counter
```

The change here is that when we set a variable in Bash we don't include the $ sign at the front. Only in referencing the variable do we include the `$`.

Comment: how about taking one step further?  `awk -v RS="ttt" 'END{print NR-1}' file`

Answer (score 0):

You have some minor syntax errors there, probably you meant this:

```
counter=$(head -2000 [file name] | grep TTT | grep -o TTT | wc -l)
echo $counter
```

Notice the tiny changes I made there to make it work.

Btw the `grep TTT` in the middle is redundant, you can simply drop it, that is:

```
counter=$(head -2000 [file name] | grep -o TTT | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

grep can already do what you want: `counter=$(grep -c TTT $infile)`. You can limit the number of hits (not lines) with `-m NUM, --max-count=NUM`, which makes grep stop at the end of the file OR when `NUM` occurrences are found.